# Pick a type from one of the props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've a List component

```
type Option = {
  id: string;
};

type Props<O> = {
  options?: O[];
  option?: JSXElementConstructor<O>;
};

const List = <O extends Option>(props: Props<O>) => ...
```

and some option components like this one

```
type Props = {
  label: string;
  icon?: ElementType;
  onClick?: () => void;
};

const BasicOption = (props: Props) => ...
```

in order to get the right type I have to do this

```
const Example = () => {
  const options = [
    { id: 'a', label: 'Label A', icon: PlaceholderIcon },
    { id: 'b', label: 'Label B', icon: PlaceholderIcon },
    { id: 'c', label: 'Label C', icon: PlaceholderIcon },
    { id: 'd', label: 'Label D', disabled: true },
    { id: 'e', label: 'Label E' },
  ];

  return (
    <List<typeof options[number]>
      options={options}
      option={BasicOption}
    />
  );
};
```

is there a way to get the right typing directly from the array in order to avoid the `<typeof options[number]>` part?

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-hopper-i41uj?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Please share reproducable example. `JSXElementConstructor`, `ElementType` ? It will be the best you you share it in TS playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need infer `options` prop and bind it with `option`.

```js
import React, { JSXElementConstructor, ElementType } from "react";


export type BasicProps = {
  label: string;
  icon?: ElementType;
  onClick?: () => void;
};

export const BasicOption = ({ label, icon: Icon, onClick }: BasicProps) => (
  <div onClick={() => onClick?.()}>
    {label}
    {Icon && <Icon />}
  </div>
);


export type Option = {
  id: string;
};

export const List = <Opt extends Option, Options extends Opt[]>({
  options,
  option: Option
}: {
  options: [...Options],
  // same as typeof options[number] but Options is infered
  option: JSXElementConstructor<[...Options][number]>;
}) => (
  <div>
    {Option &&
      options &&
      options.map((option) => <Option key={option.id} {...option} />)}
  </div>
);

export default function App() {
  const options = [
    { id: "a", label: "Label A" },
    { id: "b", label: "Label B" },
    { id: "c", label: "Label C" },
    { id: "d", label: "Label D", disabled: true },
    { id: "e", label: "Label E" }
  ];

  return (
    <List options={options} option={BasicOption} />
  );
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBSAygBoCiANkiEgHYwDCENAzjFAK4bTYVW0wAVAJ5gkcAL5wAZlAgg4AIiioMCgNwBYAFDbtSAB6RYcGCLEAhFM2BoACrLDM4AXlza4ccigBGScgC44VihgGgBzTS0PGyYAfkDeajphUUiPJnpyGwBreLgACgBKFwA%20OAA3CGAAE0jxSL1DaHg0JlY4S2s0AHkwGGAmFwK8L19ybBiaQIBJVppsDKy0bIlAzpt7CEdi5zL89zgAHmrgcrhFnOccItLzmkyc2IA6IvESg48cUb9xD9xZwYAMkBRwBNDgAHoSr8okcISdyu8tIUGjotAYjPBTKI4L1%20oNXDgDjVAsFQhFtPVdOimsY5u0ADLAdquQ54uAGGC0apOPEDea4vr8pyc7m8voAbQAuiV8kTYVt8SxMAdFfzAnymJTAvL0kK2oEJU9jZqWFKVQr9VMCCREvxGCw2JwYNBDkaTVbmFKJTR2CBfFAZXUdnsDsdTkiPJ9TXBgX89UqnHHYVHzp6niAUGB8vk1UwQ0cY9kkEIrnmaE8apIcManuXJFDCjCPId4RHtCjqRjmnBqkgpCh2OR4FJ2DQMPy4ABBMDZ4q6uD0%20DlpyuCV-PAkxQoBTYb4BRQMnx%20acKCQW1Ob6qBBTeXeeY8HhRHsYdM-iC9Rq83tD3-c3l8T3od9P0%20OAtwUao-0fADHzgAARe8TmYHxKGvEwODED8N3A9CFCQaCxlg19SHfA4pVRDxlBgdgoHBfYUyOJl2hXMtPUkcsrnWHorQbSM4E7LQYSAA)

You can find more about function arguments inference in [my blog](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Comment: TS is able to infer it from [...Options][number], great!